# Guides to use Xcode Instruments needed

Tags: ios, memory-management, xcode-instruments

I am following this guide [developer instrument guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/ViewingandAnalyzingData/ViewingandAnalyzingData.html) and [RayWenderlich's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial) to view and analyze data using Instruments and I am wondering if anyone could suggest any other guide-tutorial as I have still unclear some aspects (e.g. how to determine which classes are live in memory at a particular frame and their memory footprint).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has been few days since I posted this question and in the meanwhile I found [this](http://allseeing-i.com/Performance-tips-for-Cocos2d-for-iPhone) very useful post that gives a basic introcuction on Instruments as well as other performance related optimizations I was doing without understanding fully why :).. very useful!